# Can I use a TDBLookupComboBox without a DataSource

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I need a combobox on one of my forms. I'd like to use a TDBLookupComboBox instead of a classic TComboBox because I'd like to avoid the pain of populating a TComboBox in code (I like TDBLookupComboBox's list source, etc.)

The problem is I don't have a DataSource to attach the TDBLookupComboBox to.

I took an existing TDBLookupComboBox and copied it, and removed the DataSource from it. Now when it loads, I get nothing in the pull down (actually I can't pull it down at all, maybe the data's there I just can't see it).

Is that because I've got no DataSource? Is there a workaround for this or do I have to go the TComboBox route?

Comment: You can use [TClientDataset as memory dataset](http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0150.htm) to provide DataSource for your DBLookupComboBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you should have a `TDataSource` which has to be connected to the `ListSource` property of the `TDBLookupComboBox`. Just add decent entries for `KeyField` and `ListField`. This should get it working.

Comment: Got it. The core of my issue was that the query wasn't open yet. It was being opened later than I thought in the code-base I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a provider and a query without datasource, like a query browsing a xml for exemple. Try to search from a provider, you have many thing you can do with it. And you have the possibility to override the data, so when a TDBCombo ask the provider whcih ask your component, if you override the data you reply what you want for the combo.